# Would $-3 ^{-x}$ be an exponential decay of growth?

Tags: functions

Would $-3 ^{-x}$ be an exponential decay of growth? Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: The exponent is negative, so it is decay.

Comment: Do you mean $-3^{-x}$; or do you mean $(-3)^{-x}$?

Comment: The first answer

Comment: Edited your post accordingly. It is exponential decay to zero from the negative.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $c{\left(a^{bx}\right)}$ there is exponential decay if $b$ is negative and exponential growth if $b$ is positive.

Thus for $-(3^{{-x}})$ there will be exponential decay despite $c$ being negative.

This because the rate of decay does not depend on if the $y$ value decreases as $x$ increases but if the *absolute value* of $y$ decreases as $x$ increases.Taking x-values of $1,2,3$... we get the corresponding $y$-values as $-3,-1/9,-1/27$... The $y$-values are not decreasing  but its absolute values are.

So even though$-\left(3^{-(a+1)}\right)>-\left(3^{-(a)}\right)$, since $\left|-\left(3^{-(a+1)}\right)\right|<\left|-\left(3^{-(a)}\right)\right|$ there is exponential decay.